# How to fix "*:i386 cannot be configured because *:amd64 is in a different version"?

Tags: dpkg

I've managed to break apt-get, I think it had something to do with competing versions of libqt between supercollider and Skype. When I run `apt-get -f install` I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libxml++2.6-2 libffado2 libconfig++8 libssl1.0.0:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libqt4-declarative:i386 libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 libqt4-test qdbus
Suggested packages:
  libqt4-declarative-folderlistmodel:i386 libqt4-declarative-gestures:i386 libqt4-declarative-particles:i386 libqt4-declarative-shaders:i386 qt4-qmlviewer:i386
  libqt4-dev libqt4-dev:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libqt4-declarative:i386 libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 libqt4-test qdbus
5 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 449 not upgraded.
14 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,236 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 183437 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libqt4-sql-mysql 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1 (using .../libqt4-sql-mysql_4%3a4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libqt4-sql-mysql ...
dpkg: error processing libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 (--configure):
 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1 cannot be configured because libqt4-sql-mysql:amd64 is in a different version (4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2)
dpkg: error processing libqt4-sql-mysql (--configure):
 libqt4-sql-mysql:amd64 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.2 cannot be configured because libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 is in a different version (4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386
 libqt4-sql-mysql
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I read that I could fix this by installing aptitude and removing and reinstalling broken packages, but I can't install it using dpkg.

Comment: Sirs, that question will not help him to solve his problem. It needs a specific solution, not a generic one.

Comment: @Braiam How do you know?

Comment: @Seth check the answer. He needs to remove an specific package with `dpkg` (not included in any of the answers) and then repair the other packages.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to remove packages using `dpkg` directly, for example:

```
sudo dpkg -r libqt4-sql-mysql:i386
```

You can then see if the remaining packages can be configured with

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Once everything's configured successfully, `apt-get` should be able to install `aptitude` which should be able to work out a solution to fix the dependencies.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, that fixed my problem, legend!

Comment: I love you. After looking for the packages causing the errors with `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and removing them one by one with `sudo dpkg -r...` and finally adding the new ones with `sudo dpkg -i ...` I finally got everything working again.

Answer (score 0):

Try these with terminal

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

`sudo apt-get clean`

`sudo apt-get install -f`