# libcurl4-gnutls-dev : Depends: libldap2-dev but it is not going to be installed

Tags: apt, curl

I am trying to install curl in my ubuntu server as I was getting this error -

```
fatal error: curl.h: No such file or directory
```

Below is the error -

```
username@phx7b02c-ee1b:~$ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcurl4-gnutls-dev : Depends: libldap2-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

I am not sure what wrong I am doing here?

**Update:-**

My ubuntu version -

```
username@phx7b02c-ee1b:~$ uname -a
Linux phx7b02c-ee1b 2.6.35-22-server #33-Ubuntu SMP Sun Sep 19 20:48:58 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: When you say 'trying to install' - you want to install from source, not from a package? Any particular reason?

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using? Do you have any nonstandard repositories added?

Comment: What happens if you try manually `sudo apt-get install libldap2-dev`?

Comment: If I do `sudo apt-get install libldap2-dev`  then I get another error with the same format `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libldap2-dev : Depends: libldap-2.4-2 (= 2.4.23-0ubuntu3) but 2.4.23-0ubuntu3.5 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
`

Comment: Updated my question with ubuntu version.. Not sure about repositories at all..

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this? I just ran into the same error.

Answer (score -1):

Similar to [other questions](https://askubuntu.com/a/167724/1116) about "some packages could not be installed", try

```
apt-get update
apt-get autoremove
apt-get install -f
```

Comment: still the same error... I did all the above commands..